# How to programmatically add shadow to an android view?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-view

I don't know how to explain this effect in the title, please refer to this screenshot:

[image: shadow]

In this example, when we drag the view down, since it is already the top, the page will display a slight blue light on top of the view (right below the action bar).

I am asking for some pointers on how to programmatically add it? any pointer will be helpful!

Thank you

Comment: One easy thing u can do that, add background image with shadow